# Chrome extension to change Desktop wallpaper

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm diving into the world of Chrome Extension development, primarily because there is a very small feature that is missing in Chrome that I miss dearly. The context-menu option to "Set as background/wallpaper" like that found in Firefox. Sounds trivial, but it's convenient.

I have most of the "basic" stuff worked out with the manifest file, am able to install it, even managed to get it to show up as a context menu item.

The problem obviously is that I am wanting to mess with a user's OS-level settings which is extremely difficult because of security issues (fully understand this).

I found an extension that allowed this in older versions of Chrome, and it looked like the developer used some type of .dll and C++ to accomplish this.

I'm not really sure how to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Since that Chrome doesn't allow these kind of manipulations (such as your PC's settings), you will need to create a native application that will run beside your extension. When the user chooses the image from your extension and selects "*use as wallpaper*", you will use the [**native messaging API**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to send a message to your desktop application, that will set the wallpaper (and do whatever else you can't do within a chrome extension) for you.

Comment: @SourceMatters yes, I know, but makes sense to me: imagine if developers were allowed to change your computer's settings so easily using an extension... it would have been a huge security and privacy flaw!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [chrome.wallpaper app api](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/wallpaper) to set the wallpaper after using the [messaging api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external) to send the image from your extension.

Comment: This works only on cromeOS and is experimental... not a solution at all

Comment: How do you know he has got Canary + ChromeOS?